# Opportunity STAGE picklist value need to change

Tags: apex, trigger, community, custom-object

I want to remove the NONE value from the STAGE picklist (Opportunity Standard Fields)

[image]

Comment: why do you want to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is standard functionality given by salesforce. So, you cannot change it. Event if you create a custom picklist field in salesforce, there also you will get the --None-- option.

Comment: Pankaj, thanks a lot for sharing the information. But for the custom field we can set the "record as default (So none will automatically hide)". Is their any way to put the same thing in the Standard Object Fields ??

Comment: For custom field if you click on the picklist arrow, then  --None-- will be shown to you and there is a chance that user can select it, so we cannot hide it at all.